# How to modify the correspondence between palettes and colors in PIL.Image

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library, pixel

**Idea:**
A picture has only three colors, black is used as background, red is used to represent objects, and gray is used to represent ignored objects
And I understand that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the palette and each color, as the code below conceals, but I want to change this mapping relationship and save it

**Now:**

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('a.png')

# Get palette and reshape into 3 columns
palette = np.array(im.getpalette(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape((256,3))
```

In 'P' mode, the representation between color and color plate is as follows:

```
[[  0   0   0]      <--- first entry is black----0
 [128   0   0]      <--- second is red      -----1
 [224 224 192]      <--- grey padding to end-----2   
 [  3   3   3]
 [  4   4   4]
 [  5   5   5]
 [  6   6   6]
 ...
 ...
 [253 253 253]
 [254 254 254]
 [255 255 255]]
```

**What I want:**

```
[[  0   0   0]      <--- first entry is black----0
 [128   0   0]      <--- second is red      -----1
 [  2   2   2]      <--- third is sparse    -----None  
 [  3   3   3]
 [  4   4   4]
 [  5   5   5]
 [  6   6   6]
 ...
 ...
 [253 253 253]
 [254 254 254]
 [224 224 192]]      <--- grey padding to end-----255
```

***What I done***

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('a.png')

# Get palette and reshape into 3 columns
palette = np.array(im.getpalette(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape((256,3))

#Temporary variable storage target value
temp = copy.deepcopy(palette[2])

#Change palette[2]Value [224 224 192]  -->  [2 2 2]  
palette[2] = (2,2,2)

#Change palette[255]Value [255 255 255] -->[224 224 192]
palette[255] = temp

# got a new plaette
aa = palette.flatten().tolist()

#put in im 
im.putpalette(aa)
```

From the above code, I get a result like this

```
[[  0   0   0]      <--- first entry is black----0
 [128   0   0]      <--- second is red      -----1
 [  2   2   2]      <--- third is           -----2  
 [  3   3   3]
 [  4   4   4]
 [  5   5   5]
 [  6   6   6]
 ...
 ...
 [253 253 253]
 [254 254 254]
 [224 224 192]]
```

Comment: I don't get, what you actually want to achieve (what's the difference between the expected and actual palette?). Do you want to have all image values `2 ... 255` to be the same colour? Should that color be `[224, 224, 192]` (I'd call it light yellow, not gray)? If so, you need to set `palette[i] = (224, 224, 192)` for all `i = 2 ... 255`. As far as I know, there's no implicit continuation of a single color in Pillow's color palettes!?

Comment: It's really not very clear what you are trying to do or what the problem is. Please click `edit` under your question and try to improve it. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your reply,I would re-edited it as soon as possible